# Text-to-speech pass string to speak

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-synthesis

I’m new in programming, so need your help, just trying to make program with Text to Speech C++ in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 using Speech Synthesizer object in a CLR Console application. But I can't figure out, how to get line through the variable "t" to speak not only synth->Speak("Line saved"); and synth->Speak("Line exist"); , but with "t" like this: "Line (text line) exist". So how can I pass a string to the `Speak` function?
Can you help me figure out:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Speech::Synthesis;
using namespace System::IO;

const string FILE_NAME = "lines.txt";

vector<string> getFileLines(string file) {
    ifstream in(FILE_NAME);
    vector<string> lines;
    for (string line; getline(in, line); ) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    return lines;
}

string getUserInput() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    return str;
}

int main() 

{

    vector<string> lines = getFileLines(FILE_NAME);

    ofstream fileOut(FILE_NAME, ios::app);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)

    {

    cout << "Write: > ";
    std::string t = getUserInput();

    auto it = std::find(lines.begin(), lines.end(), t);

    if (it == lines.end()) {

        fileOut << t << endl;
        lines.push_back(t);

        cout << "Line \"" << t << "\" saved.\n";

        SpeechSynthesizer^ synth = gcnew SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth->Speak("Text saved");

    }

    else 

    {

        cout << "LIne \"" << t << "\" exist.\n";

        SpeechSynthesizer^ synth = gcnew SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth->Speak("Line exist");


    }
} 

    cout << endl;
    getUserInput();
    return 0;
}
```

and this way with marshal:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace msclr::interop;  
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Speech::Synthesis;
using namespace System::IO;

const string FILE_NAME = "lines.txt";

vector<string> getFileLines(string file) {
    ifstream in(FILE_NAME);
    vector<string> lines;
    for (string line; getline(in, line); ) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    return lines;
}

string getUserInput() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    return str;
}

int main() 

{

    vector<string> lines = getFileLines(FILE_NAME);

    ofstream fileOut(FILE_NAME, ios::app);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)

    {

    cout << "Write: > ";
    std::string t = getUserInput();

    auto it = std::find(lines.begin(), lines.end(), t);

    if (it == lines.end()) {

        fileOut << t << endl;
        lines.push_back(t);

        cout << "Line \"" << t << "\" saved.\n";

        String^ str = marshal_as<String^>(str);
        std::string line = "Line " + t + " exists!"; 
        synth->Speak(marshal_as<String^>(line));

    }

    else 

    {

        cout << "LIne \"" << t << "\" exist.\n";

        String^ str = marshal_as<String^>(str);
        std::string line = "Line " + t + " exists!"; 
        synth->Speak(marshal_as<String^>(line));

    }
} 

    cout << endl;
    getUserInput();
    return 0;
}
```

I got this errors:

> Error C4996
>   'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>:‌​:marshal_as':
>   This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file
>   needed for this conversion is not included.
>
> Error C2065 '_This_conversion_is_not_supported': undeclared identifier
>   X_TTS2 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   14.0\vc\include\msclr\marshal.h 219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation:

[marshal_as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx)

> **If you try to marshal a pair of data types that are not supported, `marshal_as` will generate an error C4996 at compile time.** Read the message supplied with this error for more information. The C4996 error can be generated for more than just deprecated functions. One example of this is trying to marshal a pair of data types that are not supported

The supported conversions are documented:

[Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

The `marshal_as()` function supports marshaling a `std::string` to a `System::String^` if you use `marshal_cppstd.h`, which your example does:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

std::string line = "Line " + t + " exists!"; 
synth->Speak(marshal_as<String^>(line));
```

So the error you show does not make sense, unless it is referring to this statement:

```
String^ str = marshal_as<String^>(str);
```

You are trying to marshal a `String^` to a `String^`, which is not a supported marshal conversion. Also, using a variable in the same statement that declares it is undefined behavior anyway, so you need to remove the statement completely as it is useless.

Alternatively, `marshal_as()` supports marshaling a `const char*` if you use `marshal.h`:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

std::string line = "Line " + t + " exists!";
synth->Speak(marshal_as<String^>(line.c_str()));
```

Comment: _hello, thank you for your feedback, very helpful, so seems I can use it this way,  works  `#include <msclr\marshal.h>

std::string line = "Line " + t + " exists!";
synth->Speak(marshal_as<String^>(line.c_str()));`

Comment: @ztores you can, yes. `marshal_as <String^>(line)` should also work, as `std::string`->`String^` is a supported and documented conversion.